# How to display one Chrome notification at a time?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a Chrome Extension right now, and I'm running into a problem where the same notification is created and displayed a bunch of times. I was wondering if there is a solution on how to check and make sure that if there is already a notification, to not create a new one. Here's my code on how the notifications are created:

```
async function alert() {
  console.log("Alert getting created");
  var result = await getExpiredIndices();
  var numberOfExpiredTabs = result.expiredTabArray.length;

    var id = uuidv4();

  var msg = `Ta daa! Your tab(s) are ready.`;
  chrome.notifications.create(
    id,
    {
      type: "basic",
      iconUrl: "assets/icons/pondr_128.png",
      title: "Pondr",
      message: msg,
      priority: 2,
      requireInteraction: true,
      buttons: [
        {
          //get indexes from storage pop them when user re-opens tabs
          title: "Open",
        },
        {
          title: "Later",
          //get indexes, shift all times, pop them since they are no longer in the outdated subarray
        },
      ],
    }

  );
}

chrome.notifications.onButtonClicked.addListener(async function (
  notifId,
  btnIdx
) {
  var result1 = await getExpiredIndices();
  var result2 = await getAllTabsArray();
  var expiredTabArray = await result1.expiredTabArray;
  var allTabsArray = await result2.allTabsArray;

    if (btnIdx === 0) {
      //if yes open tabs
      console.log("hit yes");
      console.log("Before popping allTabsArray: ", allTabsArray);
      console.log("Before popping expiredTabsArray: ", expiredTabArray);
      openTabsNow(expiredTabArray, allTabsArray);
    } else if (btnIdx === 1) {
      console.log("hit later");

      console.log("Before popping allTabsArray: ", allTabsArray);
      console.log("Before popping expiredTabsArray: ", expiredTabArray);
      openTabsLater(expiredTabArray, allTabsArray);
      //if no reapply reminder-setting
      //FOR TIME BEING: will be hardcoded to push all items 3 hrs forward
  }
});
```

Comment: Specify notificationId. [chrome.notifications.create](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/notifications/#method-create)

Comment: @NorioYamamoto so this function is actually meant to be called multiple times, but i just don't want the notification to be displayed multiple times. if i set a unique id, i noticed that it will continue to be called multiple times (since each id is unique). should i be setting a static id instead?

Comment: i've updated my code to reflect the change

Comment: you should let us know when this notification first appears and when it recurs at other unwanted times. Basically the code you posted is not enough to understand the problem.